# What do those numbers in the "uname -r" output mean?

Tags: linux, centos, command

When I run "uname -r" command on CentOS I get the following output:
3.10.0-693.21.1.el7.x86_64
What does the part of the output "693.21.1" mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Packages are released in two forms : "releases" and "updates" to releases. The other answers explain this part better.

For example, RHEL-7.4 came with kernel version 3.10.0-693. And in RHEL-7.5 it was 3.10.0-862. ( See [here](https://access.redhat.com/articles/3078) ). An important difference is that releases have only one number after the '-' instead of 3. The rest numbers are used to indicate bugs & security fixes and are used incrementally ( See [here](https://git.centos.org/summary/rpms!kernel.git) ) . See **SPECS/kernel.spec** in the commitdiff here [here](https://git.centos.org/commitdiff/rpms!kernel.git/f1afddac0d673730c2a6d73b015bc247c4ce582b) for an illustration. The example you are taking is an updated kernel.

Answer (score 2):

In a nutshell: `upstream-RedHat`.

The part before the dash (`3.10.0`) is the version number of the upstream sources that this kernel package is based on. Red Hat takes a particular release of the Linux kernel and keeps it throughout the lifetime of a major release (so all RHEL 7.x releases use kernel 3.10.0, RHEL 6.x use 2.6.32, etc.). They make a lot of patches to fix bugs and support newer hardware. The numbers after the dash (`693.21.1`) are the number of the RHEL/CentOS release of the package, and `el7` means that the package is for all 7.x releases of RHEL/CentOS.

I don't know why the release number is divided into several parts. The first number is *not* aligned with upstream maintenance release numbers, and it isn't the source version number either since there are source differences between x.y.z1 and x.y.z2.

Answer (score 1):

That is the minor release update portion of the kernel version. If you have multiple kernels installed, run one of the following:

```
rpm -qa kernel\*
rpm -qa | grep kernel
```

You'll get an output showing the releases and minor release updates of all of the installed kernels. On my system, I get this:

```
kernel-tools-libs-3.10.0-862.3.2.el7.x86_64
kernel-3.10.0-862.2.3.el7.x86_64
kernel-3.10.0-862.3.2.el7.x86_64
kernel-3.10.0-693.11.6.el7.x86_64
kernel-3.10.0-693.17.1.el7.x86_64
kernel-tools-3.10.0-862.3.2.el7.x86_64
kernel-3.10.0-693.21.1.el7.x86_64
```

As you can see, I have `3.10.0-862.2.3`, `3.10.0-862.3.2`, `3.10.0-693.17.1.`, and 3.10.0-693.11.6. You may have more or less depending on what's installed.

Comment: Could you be more specific what each number in the "693.21.1" represents?

Comment: @Noobo: They're arbitrary, monotonic numbers. They have no specific meaning other than what the changelog says they have.

Comment: @Ignacio they’re not quite arbitrary, there is significance to how they vary.

Answer (score -2):

`uname -r` returns the major part of the OS release.

Related is `uname -v` that returns the minor part of the OS release.

This is true for all platforms except "Alien UNIX" known as AIX, where uname -r and uname -v are confused.

Comment: No it doesn't. `uname -r` returns which kernel version you're running, that has nothing to do with what OS you're on.